# How to use dynamic routing in React router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a callback link `https://localhost:3000/callback?code=1234`

How do you provide a dynamic route for the code? You are not allowed to replace the `"?"` with a `"/"`.

So I would like to have something like this:

```
<Route path="callback?{dynamic data here}" element={Component } />
```

I'm using `react-router@6`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The queryString part of a URL isn't considered when using the path part of a URL to match and render routes. The route should specify only the path that it needs to match, and the routed component then needs to read the queryString parameters it needs.

Example:

```
<Route path="/callback" element={<Component />} />
```

The dynamic part is in how you link/navigate to the `"/callback"` route.

- Using a [`Link`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#link) component

  ```
   <Link
     to={{
       pathname: "/callback",
       search: `?code=${code}`, // inject code value into template
     }}
   >
     Code
   </Link>
  ```
- Using the [`Navigate`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navigate) component

  ```
   <Navigate
     to={{
       pathname: "/callback",
       search: `?code=${code}`, // inject code value into template
     }}
   />
  ```
- Using [`navigate`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate) function

  ```
   navigate({
     pathname: "/callback",
     search: `?code=${code}`, // inject code value into template
   });
  ```

The `Component` should use the [useSearchParams](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usesearchparams) hooks to access the queryString parameters.

For URL `"/callback?code=1234"`

```
const Component = () => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const code = searchParams.get("code"); // "1234"

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use link dynamically.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  /* Links */
  {listofcodes.map(x=> (<Link to={'callback/' + x.code} />)}

  /* Component */
  <Route path="callback/:code" component={callback} />
</BrowserRouter>

class callbackextends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.match.params.code}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use navigate

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

let navigate = useNavigate();

 navigate({
  pathname: '/callback',
  search: `?code=${data}`,
});
```

Then use `useLocation` to get the code from url.

```
const search = useLocation().search;
const id = new URLSearchParams(search).get("code");
```

Helpful [link](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/navigate-to-url-query-strings-search-params-react-router)